# Стили для шаблона gantry

Tags: php, css, joomla

Скажите, пожалуйста, где можно поменять стили для шаблона gantry.
Кеш я очистила, в настройке шаблона и настройках сайта(не кешировать файлы).

Я прочитала, что нужно создать папку scss (в ней файл custom.scss) в папке custom шаблона.Вопрос где прописать подключение стилей...,
типа gantry->addStyle?

Скажите, пож-ста, что можно редактировать? я так поняла css-compiled трогать нельзя, так как создаются кешем.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Создаете файл gantry-custom.css в папке сss. Его и правите.(если версия 3.)